# get custom attribute from html tag

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, bpopup

this is my code:

```
<span class="button small pop1" data-bpopup='{"transition":"slideDown","speed":850,"easing":"easeOutBack"}'>Pop it up</span>
```

How can I get data-bopopup attribute with jQuery?

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get the whole thing:

```
$('.button').data('bpopup')
```

To get the `transition` value, you can do:

```
$('.button').data('bpopup').transition;
```

Answer (score 2):

Use jQuery.data

```
var bpopup = $(".button.small.pop1").data("bpopup");
```

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
var bpopup = $(".button.small.pop1").data("bpopup");
alert(bpopup);
```